# Any code to convert tensorflow model to caffe model?

Tags: deep-learning, nvidia, tensorflow, tensorrt

My end goal is to use the TensorRT to optimize my model for deployment. I am doing my experiments in tensorflow. But the TensorRT requires the input model in caffemodel format.

Answer (score 0):

As of TensorRT 2.1, there is no support to convert TensorFlow model. This might be supported in the future.

You might want to explore options to convert TensorFlow model to Caffe and then convert that using TensorRT into an inference engine.

Answer (score 0):

New TensorRT 3 added support for TensorFlow.

Comment: Instead of giving the same answer to questions, you should generally flag the questions as duplicates.